# Close angular material menu from controler

Tags: angular, angular-material2

It may sound a bit weird, but I am not able to close Angular Material menu from my controller.

Button opening menu:

```
<md-icon class="add-note__icon" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="paletteMenu">
    palette
</md-icon>
```

Menu:

```
<md-menu #paletteMenu="mdMenu">
  <div
    (click)="setColor($event, 'white')"
    mdTooltip="White"
  ></div>
  ...
</md-menu>
```

And in my controller I have a reference to my menu:

```
@ViewChild('paletteMenu') menu: any;
```

And function which should close it:

```
setColor(event, color) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.menu.closeMenu();
}
```

Every time I am clicking on one of options, I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: this.menu.closeMenu is not a function
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Does it ever exist closeMenu() ?

Comment: Does openMenu() work if you reverse the situation in your code?

Comment: Or replace with     (click)="setColor($event, 'white'); paletteMenu.closeMenu()" and remove it from setColor()

Comment: It was for debugging purpose....

Comment: Do you get the same message or it doesn't do anything?

Comment: Read the doc again: it's for MdMenuTrigger and not the menu

Comment: Set up a plunker and I will try to fix it

Comment: here's your [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/C9KyItvFxrvpcFEnK029?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`closeMenu()` is a function of `MdMenuTrigger`, not `MdMenu`, that's why that error is occurring. Create a reference for `mdMenuTrigger` in your icon and use it in the component code.

html:

```
<md-icon class="add-note__icon"
         #paletteMenuTrigger="mdMenuTrigger"
         [mdMenuTriggerFor]="paletteMenu">
    palette
</md-icon>
```

ts:

```
export class SelectFormExample {

  @ViewChild('paletteMenuTrigger') menu: any;

  setColor(event, color) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.menu.closeMenu();
  }
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/jP7UBrRgPDFGWFJaMreN?p=preview)

Comment: It's working! Thank you! Docs were not so clear about it.. at least for me.